# Python: Sum entries in list of tuples entries with case sensitive keys?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples holding hashtags and frequencies for example:

```
[('#Example', 92002),
 ('#example', 65544)]
```

I want to sum entries which have have the same string as the first entry in the tuple (but a different case-sensitive version), keeping the first entry with the highest value in the second entry. The above would be transformed to:

```
[('#Example', 157,546)]
```

I've tried this so far:

```
import operator

for hashtag in hashtag_freq_list:
    if hashtag[0].lower() not in [res_entry[0].lower() for res_entry in res]:
        entries = [entry for entry in hashtag_freq_list if hashtag[0].lower() == entry[0].lower()]
        k = max(entries,key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]  
        v = sum([entry[1] for entry in entries])
        res.append((k,v))
```

I was just wondering if this could be approached in a more elegant way?

Comment: Sorry guys, quite right.

Comment: do you care which capitalization is kept?

Comment: @haavee Ideally that with the maximum frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use dictionary

```
data = [('#example', 65544),('#Example', 92002)]

hashtable = {}

for i in data:

    # See if this thing exists regardless of casing
    if i[0].lower() not in hashtable:

        # Create a dictionary
        hashtable[i[0].lower()] = {
            'meta':'',
            'value':[]
        }

        # Copy the relevant information
        hashtable[i[0].lower()]['value'].append(i[1])
        hashtable[i[0].lower()]['meta'] = i[0]

    # If the value exists
    else:

        # Check if the number it holds is the max against 
        # what was collected so far. If so, change meta
        if i[1] > max(hashtable[i[0].lower()]['value']):
            hashtable[i[0].lower()]['meta'] = i[0]

        # Append the value regardless
        hashtable[i[0].lower()]['value'].append(i[1])

# For output purposes
myList = []

# Build the tuples
for node in hashtable:
    myList.append((hashtable[node]['meta'],sum(hashtable[node]['value'])))

# Voila!
print myList
# [('#Example', 157546)]
```

Comment: Would this always keep the maximum as `meta`? Reversing the input (`data = [('#example', 65544), ('#Example', 92002)]`) would give: `[('#example', 157546)]`

Comment: @jfive Fixed. Let me know what you think

Comment: looks much better. I originally though this to be a more trivial problem. Recently, I have been working a lot with the built-in functionality of Pandas

Comment: @jfive always easier to code from scratch :D Also it solves the problem far faster ;)